# Cakephp 3 Localization issue

Tags: cakephp, localization

I'm using the localization feature to translate my app in French, but I'm running into some constraints I was not expecting.

In the **default.po** file, when I set:

```
msgid "MainLoginAccountLocked"
msgstr "Votre compte a été verrouillé."
```

It works fine. I can see the message translated.

But when I set:

```
msgid "Main Login Account Locked"
msgstr "Votre compte a été verrouillé."
```

It's not working. I get the "Main Login Account Locked" key instead of the translation.

Is there limitations in the msgid values? Or restricted values?
I've found nothing in the doc that could help me.

Comment: There is no such restriction. Don't forget to clear the cache after making changes (`tmp/cache/persistent`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no limitations of having spaces in the msgid, I use it all the time.

@Nds's advice is pertinent: clear your cache.

In the past I also ran with problem on the compiles version of the .po file that needed to be regenerated.

Carefully verify the spaces at the end and beginning of the string.

Maybe also you should verify the encodings involved. If you are using UTF-8 everywhere (as I hope), it shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: It looks like its a cache issue. I clear the cache each time by deleting the files in /tmp/cache/persistent, but there's a kind of lag. It might be a cache issue on the server side. (I can't touch the config of the server because I'm on a shared server).